# I need to keep multiplying found values by two with a list and a value

Tags: python

They gave me the first two lines of code.  I thought I knew how to do it but I don't really understand what I'm missing.

```py
class Solution:
    def findFinalValue(self, nums: List[int], original: int) -> int:
        if original in nums:
            for original in nums:
                original = original * 2
            print(original)
        else:
            print(original)
            
yeyo = Solution()
yeyo.findFinalValue()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and explaining what the code is supposed to do and why you think it's not working?

Comment: Also, why is the return value `int` if you haven't added a `return` statement anywhere?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the edit.
Well, this is a problem a page gave me to resolve. The class and defined function were written by them and need to be in the code. I just started with classes and objects and I'm struggling a bit to understand how to use them.
The supposed input is a list and an original number, I have to find if the number is in the list, if it is, it needs to be multiplied by 2 and the result needs to be checked again to find it in the list until the num doesn't match anymore. In case the original num is not in the list, the output should be that same number.

Comment: Also, sorry for the typing and orthographic errors, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to accomplish?

```py
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def findFinalValue(self, number_list: List[int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], search_value: int = 9) -> int: # Added some default values to test without adding parameters
        _done = False # Created a bool value to act as a switch to disable the while loop
        original_number = search_value # saving the original value since im recycling the original var below
        while _done is False: # Keep doing until the switch above is turned off
            if search_value in number_list: # The condition you needed set
                search_value *= 2 # that action if condition is met
            else:
                _done = True # the off "switch"
        return "Original Number: {} Search value multiplied up to: {}".format(original_number, search_value) # returns both using a formatted string
        #return original_number # Uncomment this line and delete the other return to only return the original number

            
yeyo = Solution()
yeyo.findFinalValue([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 2)
```

Comment: Yes!, but just output the one you called search value multiplied up to. Could you explain to me the things you added?

Comment: I added some brief comments, let me know if theres anything to expand upon!